# Modeling entity with nullable id

Tags: php, model, doctrine

Why there is practice of modeling entities with nullable id, what's the point? Only reason i can see is that, there could be an issue with access to this property before it was initialized. Is there any other reason?

Here's an example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ApiResource(mercure: true)]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Greeting
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public string $name = '';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any research yourself? The internet provied a lot of articles on that topic.

Comment: @jasie I googled this topic and this QA came up 2nd position. So your comment telling me to Google it isn't very useful. I also struggle to find articles on this topic tbh

Answer (score 0):

if you generate SQL code from this mapping, the field `id` will be NOT NULLABLE.

To be it nullable you need to configure in this way:

`#[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER, nullable: true)]`
by default it is `false`.

declaring your field `private ?int $id = null` does not make it nullable in DB.

You can do it nullable (but not primary key) in cases where you want access it before it is set.
If you define it not nullable:

```php
private int $id;
public function getId(): int
   {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

and if you access it before it is persisted (or field is initialized)
`$greeting->getId()`; you will get

invalid type error

or starting from PHP v7.4 "Typed property must not be accessed before initialization" error